# Dynamically generated select won't stay open

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

I have a `select` element that is populated from files on a server and is created by loading a `php` script. It updates properly when new files are created or deleted, but it will not stay open upon clicking. It flashes open and disappears so I don't have a chance to select an option. Is there something in my code that is causing this behavior?

Here is my form and script that calls the PHP file:

```
<form action="/server/php/data/process.php" method="post">
     <select class="ui mini fluid search dropdown" id="templateSelection" type="text" name="selectTemplate" style="height:30px;border:2px solid #ccc;border-radius:none;" onchange="loadTemplate()">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Template</option>
     </select>
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
     $.ajaxSetup ({
         cache: false
     });
     $("#templateSelection").click(function(){
       $(this).load('select_template.php');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Here is `select_template.php`:

```
<?php
     foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/server/php/data/*.json') as $filename){
     $filename = basename($filename);
     echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is down to the browser renderer updating the options. It's a very odd way of doing what you require though. I'd suggest making the AJAX request when the page loads - or even just retrieving them on the server before the page loads and avoiding the AJX completely. It seems to server no useful purpose

Comment: If it needs to be dynamic based on some other inputs, do the AJAX when you change those inputs, not when the user clicks on the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to a `click` function. That means, for every click you will reload the `select`. Use this script instead, to populate on page load and run only once:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });
  $("#templateSelection").load('select_template.php');
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to update this list without refreshing the page, though. Is there another way to load the php file upon interacting with the select? I really don't want to have a refresh button...updating the options needs to appear to happen automatically.

Comment: You can add a button and bind the click function to this button, that you refresh your `select`.

Comment: In effect a refresh button? I'm trying to avoid an additional click by the user and create the appearance of an auto-update. Is there an event that I can bind to (other than onchange) when a `select` element opens?

Comment: With my code the select options will be loaded at the page load. I can't see a reason tu update after that. It's like the user will click again and again on the select and expecting a different data. It makes no sense. The common use is to click on some select, and then load a different on with a filter based on the first select.

Comment: This `select` exists in a tab. The user can click on a different tab on that page and create a new file on the server. Then when they click back to the this tab the new file needs to be available for select (without refreshing the page). Does that make sense?

Comment: That's actually what I could do, like you said, except upon file creation I could trigger the `select` update upon clicking the save button, perhaps after a little delay.